# Working remotely with an local IDE

Tags: ide, remote-debugging

i am taking a course on GPU programming.
There is no IDE on the University Computers. Only text-editors, which is kind of a pity.

We are obligated to compile our code on the university machines, since they want to be able to compare the programs the students have produced with each other students code.

I want to use an IDE, because i think it makes things sooo much easier ( for example debugging )
My actual procedure is : i copy the files to my machine (via scp), code in Xcode , save ...
copy the files to remote machine, and compile it (via ssh)

So my question is:
**Is there a way i can use an IDE like Eclipse or Xcode that can this automatically ?**
alternatively
**How would you handle the "Work locally;compile on remote machine"-problem ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using git (http://github.com/) to solve your work-local, compile-remote problem. You can set up a git repository on the remote machine, and push your commits to it when you're ready to try compiling it. It also means that if any change breaks the compile - you can remove it without affecting any of the other things you've changed.